# Check for perfect square

Tags: elementary-number-theory, square-numbers

I want to check if $2021m-1$ is a perfect square.

Let's suppose that it is. Then there is an interger n such that $$n^2=2021m-1\Rightarrow n^2=43\cdot 47m-1$$ How can we continue?

Comment: Reduce mod $\,p=43\,$ then apply the ubiquitous linked theorem in the dupes.

Comment: So we get $n^2=42\pmod 43$,right? @BillDubuque

Comment: Yes, $\,n^2\equiv -1\pmod{\!43}\,$ so the linked theorem applies.